# C# app fall down when use Task in PCL

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I've created PCL Library:
here code:http://dumpz.org/1131545/.
In this PCL I've created an interface and class, that class call an method of this interface with Task.
Next I've added C# Class Library project, added reference to pcl and implemented this interface(http://dumpz.org/1131549/).
After it, I've added ConsoleApp, added reference to PCL and added implemented from C# CLP as a link to files.(http://dumpz.org/1131550/)

```
namespace PortableClassLibrary1
{
public interface test
{
    void test();
}
public class Class1
{
    test Test;
    public Class1(test Test)
    {
        this.Test = Test;
    }
    public Task<bool>  Call()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                Test.test();
                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
}
}
```

in C# CLP:

```
class Impl:test
{
    public Impl()
    {

    }
    public void test()
    {
        CookieContainer s = new CookieContainer();
    }
}
```

Console App:

```
 class Program
{
    static Class1 s;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        s = new PortableClassLibrary1.Class1(new Impl());
        test();
    }

    static async void test()
    {
        bool x = await s.Call();
        if(x == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("");
        }
    }
}
```

But when I call implemented method app fall down.
Please explain me why?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please add your code into the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `await`, control is yielded back to the caller. In your app, that means that when you `await s.Call()`, control yields back to `test` which is the last method inside `Main`, which then finishes execution and closes the console app.

What you have to do is explicitly call `Wait` on the `Task`

```
class Program
{
   static Class1 s;
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       s = new PortableClassLibrary1.Class1(new Impl());
       test().Wait();
}

static async Task test()
{
    bool x = await s.Call().ConfigureAwait(false);
    if(x == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("");
    }
}
```

Comment: You also need to make `test()` into `async Task` method.

Comment: Thank you @svick, didnt notice it was void returning. Fixed